# If row contains word "Hello" copy all filled cells from that column to another sheet and paste it in column "A"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will look for word "Hello" in sheet nr.1 in a variable row. Once detected, it should copy all filled cells under this word and paste it in sheet nr.2 under on column "B".
I have several issues here, how to find the cell that has this word and copy all filled cells under this address and paste them into another sheet under column B.

I would really appreciate if somebody could give me some examples if this kind of exercise.

---

```
With Sheets("GCC1")
        lastrowGCC1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

arr1 = Array("K", "P", "Q", "AA")
arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O")
  For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    With Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning")
         lastrow = Application.Max(n, .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
         .Range(.Cells(n, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
         Sheets("GCC1").Range(arr2(i) & lastrowGCC1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  'change to "GCC1" or use number index
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A:A") 'range to search
    lastrowGCC1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = rng(lastrowGCC1, 1)
    i = 1
        With rng
    Set cellFound = .Find(what:="Hello", After:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
                Do
                    ws2.Cells(i, 2) = ws1.Range(cellFound.Address).Value
                    ws2.Cells(i, 3) = cellFound.Address
                    i = i + 1
                    Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
                Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
             End If
        End With
End Sub
```

This function finds all cells addresses from column "A" in worksheet 1 with "Hello" written, then write the values on column "B" and addresses on column "C" from worksheet 2.

In Worksheet (1) you have:

```
+---+-------+
|   |   A   |
+---+-------+
| 1 | Hello |
| 2 | Hello |
| 3 | Hello |
| 4 |       |
| 5 |       |
| 6 |       |
| 7 |       |
| 8 |       |
| 9 | Hello |
+---+-------+
```

And the output on Worksheet(2) is:

```
+---+-------+------+
|   |   B   |  C   |
+---+-------+------+
| 1 | Hello | $A$1 |
| 2 | Hello | $A$2 |
| 3 | Hello | $A$3 |
| 4 | Hello | $A$9 |
+---+-------+------+
```

ps.: if your range is too large, consider using a match method with dictionary, like: [Optimise compare and match method using scripting.dictionary in VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142294/optimise-compare-and-match-method-using-scripting-dictionary-in-vba)